# JSP Servlet displaying inexisting data

Tags: java, jsp

I created a simple servlet which was printing some message like this:

```
@WebServlet("/servletExample")
public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello there");

    }
```

Everything worked well.
Then i created 2 jsp pages like this:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="servletExample">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    First name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
                </td>               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Last name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
                </td>               
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </td>               
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

and

```
<body>
    <%
        String firstName = (String)request.getAttribute("firstname");
        String lastName = (String)request.getAttribute("lastname");

        out.println(firstName+ " "+lastName);
    %>
</body>
```

The servlet looks like this now:

```
@WebServlet("/servletExample")
public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 

        String firstName=request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastName=request.getParameter("lastname");

        if(firstName == null || lastName==null){
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            return;
        }

        request.setAttribute("firstname", firstName);
        request.setAttribute("lastname", lastName);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

When i run it i see that form but when i submit i see "Hello there" from the example i did 2 days ago. Whatever i do i see that.
What do i have to clean? 
What am i missing?

Edit: I use eclipse and tomcat 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are in Eclipse, stop your Tomcat server, select your project, in Eclipse's menu select Project and `Clean` and then `Build Project`. Then restart your Tomcat server and try again.

Eclipse uses the last built project version with Tomcat every time you run. You need to clean up the project and rebuild it for Eclipse and Tomcat to refresh the changes.

Comment: Yeah, Eclipse can be annoying sometimes, always having to refresh. Good luck!